# Parsing date in dart/Flutter to calculate day difference

Tags: date, flutter, time, dart

I am struggling to find a way to parse 2 YYYY-MM-DD dates in dart/Flutter. I need to find out whether a given date is before another date in terms of number of days in utc. If they are the same or it is in the future it should return false.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with intl package (https://pub.dev/packages/intl) you can convert those strings to actual date objects and then compare them easily

Answer (score 0):

just compare them with

```
DateTime date1 = DateTime.now();
DateTime date2 = DateTime.now();

if(date1.millisecondsSinceEpoch > date2.millisecondsSinceEpoch){
    return false;
}
return true;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try out this package, [Jiffy](https://github.com/jama5262/jiffy)

First, parse the string into a Jiffy instance

```
Jiffy jiffy1 = Jiffy.parse("2019-12-01", isUtc: true);
Jiffy jiffy2 = Jiffy.parse("2019-12-20", isUtc: true);
```

Next is to check if it is the same or in the future in terms of days

```
jiffy1.isSameOrBefore(jiffy2, Units.DAY); // true
```

You can also check if it is the same or in the past in terms of days

```
jiffy1.isSameOrAfter(jiffy2, Units.DAY); // false
```

Check out this [documentation](https://github.com/jama5262/jiffy) for more

Hope this helped